# Download binary file from url using JAVA giving 403 error but PHP working fine

Tags: java, php, curl, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-403

I wrote some **java** code for download mp3 from one website. It is giving **403** status code. I googled and got some idea that i need to set ***User-Agent*** and ***Referrer*** (because they need it). I set those two still it is not working. So i captured request which i am sending to the website i got, what and all i need to send. I set all the required header and i got the same 403. I did small research on this, i used ***php*** and ***windows curl*** (curl.exe from curl.haxx.se) and it is working fine.

Here is the code which i wrote

**Java using Apache HttpClient (giving 403)**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();       
GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://redu.su/download_file.php?id=7745333&filename=k-j-yesudas-mavapanisa-silpa.mp3&ts=130944042611814004&hash=b825427b3a63b28c8a4ba3b2a34294fb");
get.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
get.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36");
get.setRequestHeader("Referrer", "http://redmp3.cc/7745324/k-j-yesudas-sreeragamo.html");
httpClient.executeMethod(get); 
System.out.println(get.getStatusCode());
```

**Java using URL and  URLConnection (giving 403)**

```
URL u = new URL("http://redu.su/download_file.php?id=7745333&filename=k-j-yesudas-mavapanisa-silpa.mp3&ts=130944042611814004&hash=b825427b3a63b28c8a4ba3b2a34294fb");
HttpURLConnection  uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(); // Without type cast to HttpURLConnection , URLConnection also not working
uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36");
uc.addRequestProperty("Referrer", "http://redmp3.cc/7745324/k-j-yesudas-sreeragamo.html");
uc.connect();
System.out.println(uc.getResponseMessage());// Forbidden output
```

**PHP using curl (Getting output)**

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://redu.su/download_file.php?id=7745333&filename=k-j-yesudas-mavapanisa-silpa.mp3&ts=130944042611814004&hash=b825427b3a63b28c8a4ba3b2a34294fb");
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://redmp3.cc/7745324/k-j-yesudas-sreeragamo.html");
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36");
  $contents = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $contents;
  exit;
?>
```

**Windows curl (Getting output)**

```
curl "http://redu.su/download_file.php?id=7745333&filename=k-j-yesudas-mavapanisa-silpa.mp3&ts=130944042611814004&hash=b825427b3a63b28c8a4ba3b2a34294fb" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36" -H "Referer: http://redmp3.cc/7745324/k-j-yesudas-sreeragamo.html" --compressed
```

*What is the mistake i am doing here? Why can't i get 200 response when i do using Java?*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I get an 404 error now myself, I'm pretty confident that you have one excess `R`.

It's **Referer** not **Refer<strike>r</strike>er**

My code, based on HttpClient 4.5:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();    

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://redu.su/download_file.php?id=7745333&filename=k-j-yesudas-mavapanisa-silpa.mp3&ts=130944042611814004&hash=b825427b3a63b28c8a4ba3b2a34294fb");
        get.setHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36");
        get.setHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER, "http://redmp3.cc/7745324/k-j-yesudas-sreeragamo.html");

        HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(get); 
        System.out.println(res.getStatusLine());
```